# What is more performant: directly setting a value or first check if the value changed and then set it?

Tags: java, performance, optimization

**Option 1:**

```java
List<Object> listObjects = new ArrayList<>();
for(Object object : listObjects){
  object.setValue1("new value");
}
```

**Option 2:**

```java
List<Object> listObjects = new ArrayList<>();
for(Object object : listObjects){
  if(!object.getValue1().equals("new value"))
     object.setValue1("new value");
}
```

Which of the above options is more performant in terms of cpu and memory usage?

Additional context:
Let's imagine the objects list is pretty big and we loop through it every 5 seconds.

Comment: You should always expect `.equals` on a string to be slower than assigning a value to a field.

Comment: I hope no one is teaching you to worry about things like this.  Anyone who knows enough about Java to know how to accurately measure what's going to be an infinitesimal difference knows the difference isn't going to be worth worrying about.  You shouldn't be worrying about performance until you have a running application ***that doesn't meet performance requirements***.  And in that case, you ***measure*** your application's performance by [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) it and then - and only then - you fix the problems that profiling identified.

Comment: Micro-optimization. Pick the one which is the most readable. I would say option 1.

Comment: @AndrewHenle no, no one is haha. I just like to have the best/most performant code wherever possible.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." -- Knuth. He wrote this when c was new, and it is just as true today. Get your code fully working, then worry about improving it if this is needed.

Comment: @NomadMaker true, but I still like to have an optimized code right away :/

Comment: @OsirisTeam There are a lot of things we would like. However, optimizing code before it is needed usually takes more time than it will save. Spending days optimizing code which might save a few seconds over the lifetime of the program is foolish. First get things working, then use a profiler. I'm not saying to write bad code, just do the best you can.

Comment: @NomadMaker yeah ur right.

Comment: @OsirisTeam *I just like to have the best/most performant code wherever possible.*  Then profile your application and fix the bottlenecks when you do that.  Processors today are deeply pipelined and execute multiple instructions simultaneously.  Because of that (and lots of other reasons), the performance of most of the instructions (and most of your code) really doesn't matter at all - it's the few that actually bottleneck that control performance.  And most of the time, you won't be able to guess beforehand which lines of code generate those bottlenecks.

Comment: (cont)  So the best code is the clearest, most-understandable and most-maintainable code.  And not the code that your [WAG](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wild%20ass%20guess) assumes is the fastest.  And when you throw Java with it's just-in-time compilation and run-time optimization into the mix, it's even more difficult to predict performance.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yeah, I completely agree. I'm basically living with the illusion of having control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the test I did (openJDK 11). As I suspected,

1. "testSetValueNoCheck" and "testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic" and "testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral" are almost same which means you can ignore the difference.
2. The interesting thing is "testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic\testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral **second time**" time is **always half** the time of #1. I believe it is because *how equals is implemented in Java for String* - the functions that actual do work "StringLatin1.equals" and "StringUTF16.equals" are annotated "@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate" which may or may not happen. That also means if data is not `String`, results will differ in scenarios above based on how equals is implemented.

The "second time" case is relevant based you what you wrote:

> Additional context: Let's imagine the objects list is pretty big and we loop through it every 5 seconds.

So, in general I do agree with advice in comments - worry about performance when you  need to. Personally for me, the time is every time I finish the module and have unit tests, do performance testing. It takes day (or even less if you have automation), but I have never found it to be counter productive.

Output:

testSetValueNoCheck: 39.9644

testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic: 40.4051

testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic second time: 13.7888

testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral: 33.6455

testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral second time: 18.5136

Code:

```
    class SetValueTest {
    class MyObject {
        private String _val;
        MyObject(final String val) {
            _val = val;
        }
        
        String getValue() {
            return _val;
        }
        
        void setValue(final String val) {
            _val = val;
        }
        
    }
    
    ArrayList<MyObject> getData() {
        final ArrayList<MyObject> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            data.add(new MyObject(String.format("%d", i)));
        }
        return data;
        
    }
    
    SetValueTest() throws InterruptedException {
        long start = 0L, end = 0L; 
        
        final ArrayList<MyObject> data1 = getData();
        
        start = System.nanoTime();
        testSetValueNoCheck(data1);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("testSetValueNoCheck: " + (end - start) / 1e6);
        
        final ArrayList<MyObject> data2 = getData();
        
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
        
        start = System.nanoTime();
        testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic(data2);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic: " + (end - start) / 1e6);
        
        start = System.nanoTime();
        testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic(data2);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic second time: " + (end - start) / 1e6);
        
        
        final ArrayList<MyObject> data3 = getData();
        
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);         
        
        start = System.nanoTime();
        testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral(data3);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral: " + (end - start) / 1e6);
        
        start = System.nanoTime();
        testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral(data3);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral second time: " + (end - start) / 1e6);
        
    }
    
    void testSetValueNoCheck(List<MyObject> objs) {
        for (MyObject obj : objs) {
            obj.setValue(NewValue);
        }
    }
    
    void testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral(List<MyObject> objs) {
        for (MyObject obj : objs) {
            if (!obj.getValue().equals("new Value")) {
                obj.setValue("new Value");
            }
        }
    }       
    
    static final String NewValue = "new Value";
    
    void testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic(List<MyObject> objs) {
        for (MyObject obj : objs) {
            if (!obj.getValue().equals(NewValue)) {
                obj.setValue(NewValue);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

**SECOND ROUND**

- Changes:

--- changed the class so that and ran once per *class run* so that garbage collection\memory would not interfere with readings

--- sleep changed to 5 seconds to simulate actual scenario

--- ran each test 10 times with average as following:

testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic: Average First Time: 27.728210 Second Time: 10.979410

testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral: Average First Time: 23.161670 Second Time: 12.896330

testSetValueNoCheckStatic: Average First Time: 20.294100 Second Time: 21.679260

testSetValueNoCheckLiteral: Average First Time: 29.137620 Second Time: 19.812040

```
    static class SetValueTest {
    class MyObject {
        private String _val;
        MyObject(final String val) {
            _val = val;
        }
        
        String getValue() {
            return _val;
        }
        
        void setValue(final String val) {
            _val = val;
        }
        
    }
    
    ArrayList<MyObject> getData() {
        
        final ArrayList<MyObject> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            data.add(new MyObject(String.format("%d", i)));
        }
        return data;
        
    }
    
    private final static int SleepTime = 5000;
    private static final String NewValue = "new Value";
    
    SetValueTest(final int test) throws InterruptedException {

        final ArrayList<Double> firstTimes = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<Double> secondTimes = new ArrayList<>();
        String testName = "";
        final int times = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
            double firstTime = 0, secondTime = 0;
            final ArrayList<MyObject> data = getData();
            switch (test) {
            case 1:
                testName = "testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic";
                firstTime = testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic(data);
                secondTime = testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic(data);
                break;
            case 2:
                testName = "testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral";
                firstTime = testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral(data);
                secondTime = testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral(data);
                break;
            case 3:                 
                testName = "testSetValueNoCheckStatic";
                firstTime = testSetValueNoCheckStatic(data);
                secondTime = testSetValueNoCheckStatic(data);
                break;
            case 4:                 
                testName = "testSetValueNoCheckLiteral";
                firstTime = testSetValueNoCheckLiteral(data);
                secondTime = testSetValueNoCheckLiteral(data);
                break;
            }
            firstTimes.add(firstTime);
            secondTimes.add(secondTime);
        }
        
        double firstTimeTotal = 0, secondTimeTotal = 0;
        System.out.println("Test: " + testName);
        for (int time = 0; time < times; ++time) {
            System.out.println(String.format("First Time: %f Second Time: %f", firstTimes.get(time), secondTimes.get(time)));
            firstTimeTotal += firstTimes.get(time);
            secondTimeTotal += secondTimes.get(time);
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Average First Time: %f Second Time: %f", firstTimeTotal / times, secondTimeTotal / times));
        
        
    }
    
    double toMilliseconds(final long start, final long end) {
        return ((end - start) / 1e6);
    }
    
    double testSetValueNoCheckStatic(List<MyObject> objs) throws InterruptedException {
        
        long start = 0L, end = 0L; 
        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (MyObject obj : objs) {
            obj.setValue(NewValue);
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(SleepTime);
        return toMilliseconds(start, end);
        
    }
    
    double testSetValueNoCheckLiteral(List<MyObject> objs) throws InterruptedException {
        
        long start = 0L, end = 0L; 
        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (MyObject obj : objs) {
            obj.setValue("new Value");
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(SleepTime);
        return toMilliseconds(start, end);          
        
    }
    
    
    double testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral(List<MyObject> objs) throws InterruptedException {
        long start = 0L, end = 0L; 
        start = System.nanoTime();
        
        for (MyObject obj : objs) {
            if (!obj.getValue().equals("new Value")) {
                obj.setValue("new Value");
            }
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(SleepTime);
        return toMilliseconds(start, end);          
    }       

    
    double testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic(List<MyObject> objs) throws InterruptedException {
        long start = 0L, end = 0L; 
        start = System.nanoTime();
        
        for (MyObject obj : objs) {
            if (!obj.getValue().equals(NewValue)) {
                obj.setValue(NewValue);
            }
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(SleepTime);
        return toMilliseconds(start, end);          
        
    }
    
}
```

Actual output:

Test: testSetValueWithCheckUsingStatic
First Time: 42.110700 Second Time: 21.398500
First Time: 37.834800 Second Time: 10.124700
First Time: 18.263600 Second Time: 8.967400
First Time: 16.655500 Second Time: 7.146000
First Time: 18.729900 Second Time: 8.753300
First Time: 17.513100 Second Time: 14.622800
First Time: 24.000300 Second Time: 9.534700
First Time: 61.357000 Second Time: 11.677700
First Time: 26.832500 Second Time: 10.160400
First Time: 13.984700 Second Time: 7.408600
Average First Time: 27.728210 Second Time: 10.979410

Test: testSetValueWithCheckUsingLiteral
First Time: 54.417700 Second Time: 22.161600
First Time: 20.950000 Second Time: 14.621500
First Time: 31.008100 Second Time: 13.631600
First Time: 14.052500 Second Time: 10.490900
First Time: 20.904800 Second Time: 8.727700
First Time: 13.338300 Second Time: 13.519100
First Time: 18.740800 Second Time: 13.030500
First Time: 14.959100 Second Time: 15.166100
First Time: 25.593000 Second Time: 8.041300
First Time: 17.652400 Second Time: 9.573000
Average First Time: 23.161670 Second Time: 12.896330

Test: testSetValueNoCheckStatic
First Time: 34.467700 Second Time: 33.953200
First Time: 15.307500 Second Time: 14.245300
First Time: 34.042700 Second Time: 31.824600
First Time: 11.989300 Second Time: 12.266800
First Time: 15.556500 Second Time: 24.501000
First Time: 12.314800 Second Time: 16.539600
First Time: 14.333300 Second Time: 14.500300
First Time: 11.876900 Second Time: 21.599900
First Time: 39.020400 Second Time: 31.754800
First Time: 14.031900 Second Time: 15.607100
Average First Time: 20.294100 Second Time: 21.679260

Test: testSetValueNoCheckLiteral
First Time: 49.325300 Second Time: 27.528700
First Time: 26.355500 Second Time: 27.800100
First Time: 23.862700 Second Time: 15.576400
First Time: 25.133000 Second Time: 16.290500
First Time: 28.379000 Second Time: 18.192400
First Time: 83.170600 Second Time: 18.183800
First Time: 13.570100 Second Time: 14.341100
First Time: 11.793900 Second Time: 13.960000
First Time: 16.238900 Second Time: 30.233200
First Time: 13.547200 Second Time: 16.014200
Average First Time: 29.137620 Second Time: 19.812040

Comment: Oh wow, that's a pretty unexpected result. I thought setting the new value without checking would be faster. Could you do a second run for the testSetValueNoCheck() test too? Thanks for testing!

Answer (score 1):

My vote would be option 1:  it's shorter (ignoring the setValue2 call) and if it's an object, the assignment is just loading and storing a pointer, whereas the `equal` comparison could take a long time if the object is very big.